# Best practice for reply to thanks?

Tags: pronouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Response to “Thank you!”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/response-to-thank-you)

When somebody emails me or sends me thanks, I just reply "You're welcome."  So what will be the professional and good alternative for that?