# How is the action of replying to a thanks called?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine the following conversation

> Alice: "Here is the document you asked for."
>
> Bob: "Oh, thanks so much."
>
> Alice: "Don't mention it."

So the second person was **thanking** the first. Afterwards, Alice had a choice of expressions, as illustrated in [that question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/how-do-native-english-speakers-respond-to-thank-you). But is there a name for it? Could one fill the following

> After being thanked by Bob, Alice ______________ .

Comment: Note that I am not too strict about *single* of *single word requests*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Several answers to the question you linked in your question refer to “[acknowledging](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/acknowledge) [receipt of]” the “thank you”:

> Alice acknowledged Bob’s show of appreciation with a smile.

(from MacMillan Dictionary, definition 2)