# Most common answers for “thank you! (e g for your help)

Tags: word-choice, phrases, expressions, american-english

What are the most common answers in AmE when a person says “thank you”? Thank you;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do native English speakers respond to "Thank you"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/how-do-native-english-speakers-respond-to-thank-you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're Welcome

You're welcome is the traditional answer, and the one I use myself. However, Americans typically say the more informal answer of no big deal or no problem. Here are Ngrams for British English, American English, and all English.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+problem%2Cyou%27re+welcome%2Cno+big+deal&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20problem%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20%27re%20welcome%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cno%20big%20deal%3B%2Cc0