# What does "grandfathered in" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, meaning-in-context

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I'm only grandfathering you in because of Serena.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31391/im-only-grandfathering-you-in-because-of-serena)

Over [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59264/182162), Jeff says something using the expression "grandfathered in." What does that mean and how can it be used elsewhere?

Is it somewhat related to maybe adding or filling in the previous or missing part of a family tree? Sort of like a `rebase` in Git.