# When should "no problem" replace "you're welcome" as a response to "thank you"?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I have observed a growing trend in which people substitute "no problem" for "you're welcome" as a response to "thank you".  In particular, it seems to be an increasingly common response from servers and store clerks.

It seems to me that "no problem" isn't appropriate for *all* situations as a response to "thank you", such as when I express thanks for receiving a cup of coffee at the local doughnut shoppe.  To me, responding "no problem" to "thank you" implies there might have been a problem, which was somehow narrowly averted.

Are there specific situations in which "no problem" is appropriate to use as a substitute for "you're welcome"?

Comment: Not sure when it became common or how appropriate it is, but there are parallels in other languages. _Kein Problem_ has similar usage in German, and Spanish has _de nada_ “it's nothing.” They all have the same basic meaning as _you're welcome,_ that helping you is no trouble for the server.

Comment: @BraddSzonye Similarly, in Japanese it's "Doitashimashite", which is roughly "What have I done to deserve your thanks? I haven't done anything that you should thank me for." Most translators will just tell it means "you're welcome", though.

Comment: I've always said *no problem* much more often than *you're welcome*, which sounds stuffy to my Californian ears. What's new to me is how common the Australian *no worries* has become in the U.S.

Comment: I prefer "no problem" to "you're welcome" when a colleague thanks me for handling something that he or she didn't do quite correctly (or in some cases, at all). I suppose that under the circumstances both "you're welcome" and "no problem" are somewhat dishonest responses; but I feel more comfortable assuring the person that doing the work didn't inconvenience me excessively than in seeming to welcome such tasks.

Comment: "My pleasure" is a nice alternative.

Comment: Both of them lack imagination and as far as I'm concerned are an abuse of English. I wouldn't touch either with a barge pole, and as for 'no worries' that is even worse. (Why would anyone have the impertinence to suggest that I might be worried?) If one must speak in cliché, then '...it's a pleasure', '...don't mention it', or '...not at all', all indicate a more mature facility with the language.

Comment: Thanks are about gratitude, not creativity. And I think “no worries” means “it's ok, I wasn't inconvenienced” rather than suggesting that the recipient might be worried. And honestly, why react to pleasantries with accusations of impertinence? Accept sentiments as they're offered.

Comment: If you think "no problem" is bad... when I was growing up, my parent(s) often replied with "uh huh" (or "mmm hmmm") in informal circumstances and I didn't even realized how awkward this was until confronted with the "no problem" response and realize I have been using "uh-huh" most of the time in place of "you're welcome".

Comment: @WS2 - by "both of them", you mean "you're welcome" and "no problem"?

Comment: @ws2 seriously?? at any rate, i don't understand how, as the question states, replying "no problem" implies there was a problem. it both means and implies exactly the opposite of that. it might imply (to some) that the person who said "thank you" *thought* there might have been a problem, but that's not the intent of the phrase.

Comment: This isn't a question about English language or usage. It's a complaint about what the OP perceives as other people's bad manners.

Comment: My personal preference is "Yeah, whatever" or a slightly prolonged "Meh". Those really seem to convey the appropriate sense of informality. Seriously, though, when I was a server at a fairly nice but mid-priced steakhouse, we were always instructed to keep our customer interactions short but polite. When a customer thanked me for serving their ordered items or refilling a drink, I would usually say "Certainly" or "You're welcome" and if it was a main course or dessert, I would usually follow up immediately with "Please enjoy", to communicate my well wishes for their dining experience.

Comment: Can I just point out how bizarre it seems to say that "'no problem' ... implies that there was a problem," i.e. the literal opposite of what the phrase means? Sure, it'd be far from the only phrase that means the opposite of what it seems to, but I just find it very curious that anyone would jump to that meaning without a strong record of established usage.

Comment: "Never" is the correct answer here.   Unless you're all close friends, when of course "No prob, dude,"  or even "ahhh Go bleep yrself" might be acceptable :-)

Comment: Years (decades?) ago, comedian George Carlin complained wittily about the substitution of "No problem" for "You're welcome." I think it annoyed him, but then lots of things annoyed George. May he rest in peace.

Comment: @Michael I also grew up with people saying "uh huh" instead of "you're welcome". I always felt like bashing them in the head for it, I used to think it was so rude - that they didn't care either way. But then I realized that they're just afraid to express their emotions.

Comment: After reading this, my head literally exploded. ;)

Comment: Figuratively exploded.

Comment: I think just typical of the expanding use of 'literally' into the realm of the ridiculous. 'The Korean meat-balls are "quite literally" the dog's bollocks!'

Comment: @davidcl: And "my pleasure" is the standard response at the Chik-Fil-A restaurant chain, which seems to be spreading to other restaurants as well.

Comment: A lot of the answers here are really good. However, there's one phrase that I haven't seen mentioned yet. I find myself using "no worries" more than "no problem" or "you're welcome". I have *no idea* where or how I picked that up, but I really like it. I think it carries more of a "happy to do it" attitude and it seemingly can be used formally and informally.

Comment: @WS2 - this week's episode of Archer had an excellent example of proper figurative/literal usage; like most Archer jokes though, the punchline arrives well after the set-up.

Comment: As yet another option, try *Don't mention it* (once used quite memorably to set up a joke on The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy radio series). The implication is similar: What I did was so little trouble as to be barely worth your thanks.

Comment: What about "Sure" as a response to "Thank you"? I've heard that numerous times.

Comment: or "That's me" for echoing the "thank you", a less formal "you're welcome"

Comment: @Michael - I found "uh huh" being used a lot in Florida.  To my stereotypically polite Canadian ears it sounded sarcastic!  The first time someone said it to me I thought to myself "what, did I do something to offend them somehow?"  I eventually got used to it, but I had to be really careful not to pick it up as a habit to take home with me!

Comment: The question seems to assume that there's a correct answer, independent of what people actually do. But I'm far from sure about that. What's appropriate depends in very large part on where you are. I remember being struck when I moved to NC from the UK because people felt the need to say *anything* in response to 'thank you'. 'Thank you', for me, was typically the end of exchanges. Everything which politeness required had been said. It felt awkward to let the *other* party end it - I felt that as the recipient, I should respond further but, having thanked them, I had nothing else to say!

Comment: @Geobits, Are you sure "douitashimashite" means "What have I done to deserve your thanks"?

Comment: @Pacerier This is how it was explained to me by native speakers when I lived there. I can't say if it's a literal translation, which is why I used the *roughly* qualifier.

Comment: 'No problem' and 'You're welcome' are both fairly recent ways of responding to thanks. Older would include 'Don't mention it' and 'My pleasure.'

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_problem

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The phrase "no problem" is a short version of "It was no problem," implying that it didn't cause the person any trouble or hardship to do the thing for which they are being thanked.

It could be construed as an act of humility or deference, because they are suggesting that the action they performed, and any inconvenience it may have caused them, are unimportant relative to the positive impact to the thanking party.

Fully unpacked, it goes like this:

> "It was no problem for me to hold the door for you, because your ease of access is more important than me getting to my car faster."

Compare this with "You're welcome", which could be construed as an acknowledgement by the thanked party that they *did* do something worth thanking.

In an extreme case, this could be construed as more selfish or even arrogant, because the thanked party is allowing attention to be on them, instead of the other party.

> "You're welcome to this open door, which I am holding open."

Obviously both connotations are usually *very* minor and mostly ignored; most of the time, people choose 'you're welcome' or 'no problem' because "It's just what you say when someone thanks you." I doubt many people actually think it's arrogant to say "you're welcome" unless it's said with a rude tone of voice. However, these implications may explain why 'no problem' has become more common, and could even be seen as a more polite reply.

Comment: +1 to the spirit of this. People at my workplace are mostly informal, and I tend to reserve "you're welcome" for when something was actually difficult (in part because "it was no problem [staying up extra late]" just rings false.)

Comment: This is by far the most accurate answer here. No problem is simply a way of saying "It wasn't any trouble for me to do this."

Comment: This is absolutely the reason, following the intent of each abridged expression. That said, I agree that few stop to ponder the implications of each phrase, and its context in each situation, being that they are merely formalities. And I believe that to be the sticking point; the teaching of "manners" is a looser form of "etiquette", which is really a set of procedures for behaving "appropriately". "You are welcome [ (in|as|to|etc)...]" is deemed the "appropriate" response, despite the connotations of superiority, while "Doing this service caused me no ill effect" is not.

Comment: I don't think the difference is minor; I've never used "You're welcome" because that implicit rudeness jumped out at me even back in gradeschool...

Comment: I generally use "no problem" when I'm being thanked for a small courtesy, such as holding a door, for precisely this reason: it was no problem for me to do it.  If I'm being thanked for a gift or a larger favor (willingly given), I say "You're welcome."  On a couple of occasions I've been pressured or manipulated into a large undertaking as a "favor"; when the recipient said "Thank you" at the end, I have merely said "Hmm." in order not to encourage a repetition.

Comment: "No problem" can also be used as a response to someone politely apologizing for a very minor inconvenience. In that case, "no problem" (or "no worries" if you're Down Under) means that no harm's been done, but also implies that the apology was appreciated nonetheless. The apology is basically a "thank you (in advance) for your forgiveness for this minor faux pas/delay/whatever", so you're still responding to a "thank you" in a sense. But responding with "you're welcome" would be nonsensical.

Comment: @Seloniath: What you said is not what this answer says.   This answer does not say "it wasn't any trouble for me to do this", it says "it was no problem for me to do this because it is more important that it be done for you than any trouble resulting to me".  These are significantly different.

Comment: While one cannot argue about the semantics, I have to disagree with the general approach: if the question had been about the meaning of "Please" as in "Please, would you blah blah", your angle wouldn't work: "Your answer will please me if you deign give one"? I think it's plain wrong. This is 100% about usage and there have to be regional variations, irrespective of semantics:  In my world, "You're welcome" has come to be a reasonably polite form, while "No problem" is informal. "No problem" is what a rude person trying to be polite would say. I certainly wouldn't use it.

Comment: I agree completely with this answer (and disagree completely with PatrickT's comment). The whole point of "you're welcome" is and has always been expressing a social power dynamic by which the person who has been thanked feels entitled to receiving gratitude. I suspect this could be supported by looking for examples (in literature, cinema, etc.) where a person of lower social status says "you're welcome" to someone of higher social status; my suspicion is that these are unlikely to be found in any significant frequency.

Comment: Thus, my view of PatrickT's idea that "you're welcome" is the "polite" form and "no problem" is the "informal" form is that this is an inherently classist view; "you're welcome" is associated with "polite" usage because higher-social-status people are considered "polite", while "no problem" is associated with "informal" usage by people of lesser social status who could not get by, socially, with using "you're welcome" when it would imply an unacceptable reverse-social-power-gradient power dynamic.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am old enough to have exclusively used "You're welcome", but young enough to have mostly switched over to "No problem".  I think this answer, and the supporting comments, are missing a particular aspect of "you're welcome".  To be welcome has an implication beyond the current situation, that the one offering the help would help again, as in "you're welcome to it".

Comment: Conversely, a 'welcome' has a connotation of arrival - "you are well come - we are so glad you made the journey to come to see us ... now let's get your things unpacked and we can sit down to a beer".  As a response to 'I thank you', 'you are welcome' carries a sense of "For YOU, I'd do it for you over and over again until the end of time".  Only the biggest-hearted can afford to dole out this effusive feeling to *everyone*.  However, if you were on the receiving end and expecting 'welcome', but got 'no problem', you may be inclined to protest what it betokens.

Comment: And you can emphasize it with a "no problem at all" meaning there is nothing to worry about as it was nice to be helpful.

Comment: If I may give a counterpoint to the consensus here. To me "no problem" has always seemed more unfriendly.

In trying to unpack why, perhaps it's because if one imagines a spectrum of inconvenience (excuse the formatting here - I can't improve it):

- I enjoyed it (It's a pleasure! :)
- It was neutral. ("It wasn't a problem -- but not going to go as far as to say I *enjoyed* it)


 - It sucked, but I did it anyway for you and it left me feeling drained and irritable (not sure how you would respond here)

This is all from the perspective of the task do-er. This could be the key difference.

Answer (score 47):

The main difference is that *[you're welcome](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/you-re-welcome)* is meant to be polite while *[no problem](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/no-problem)* is meant to be friendly.

Comment: This especially makes the difference when talking about servers. Servers at "fancy" restaurants will use a more polite tone (you're there for the atmosphere), while others will try to befriend you to get a better tip.

Comment: What on earth is not friendly about 'you are welcome?'. To me 'No problem' sounds like you might not have been so helpful if it would have put you out.

Comment: @Julian It's not that "You're welcome" is unfriendly, it's that it's not actively friendly.  It's formal.  Think of it in the sense other languages have for addressing the second person, e.g., French "vous" versus "tu".  And I think you're reading *quite* a lot into "no problem", especially without context.

Comment: The answer suggested friendly and formal were antonyms. Actually it is all about context and non verbal stuff. I would be happy to receive any of these in some situations and could feel annoyed in others.

Answer (score 23):

Many languages use some form of "it's nothing" or "no problem" when a favor or nicety is done, to put the receiver of the action at ease that it was only a miniscule bit of effort to serve.

In Spanish, it's "de nada" or "no hay de qué" or "no problema" (I never hear, "you're welcome", and the last has made its way into English).

In French, it's "de rien" or "pas de quoi !" or "pas de problème" (more common than "bienvenue", in my experience).

Where "you're welcome" was much more common years ago, it's getting replaced as it has in Europe.

"Not a problem" and "it's nothing" seem to be more common in spoken English now than "you're welcome".

Comment: _THIS_  answer is the reason.  My wife is bilingual in Spanish and English being that she's Mexican and I only speak English, as I'm not Mexican =D.  That said, I've been converted to **no problem** after being around her family!

Comment: I know this is nibbling, but it would be "pas de quoi !" with a space before the exclamation mark in French. Just FYI.

Comment: Also, "bienvenue" would make absolutely no sense in this context. In fact I even wonder why English says "you're welcome".

Comment: @ArlaudPierre - I was taught to say, *bienvenue* or *avec plaisir* when someone said *s'il vous plaît*.

Comment: ****No problema* is not Spanish.**  It’s el fako Spañuolo by Anglophones.  In Spanish, one would say *ningún problema*, because English *no* is not the same as Spanish *no*, which actually equates to English *not*.  You want an adjective, not an adverb.

Comment: @tchrist - Listen, I know you studied Spanish. But about 25% of my patients speak Spanish, and I pick it all up from them. So tell them that they are **El Faking it**, because so far, though it may be idiomatic, I've had no funny looks in conversing with other Hispanics. No hay alguna problema aqui. Yes, that's how they talk. Totes El fako.

Comment: I merely posted my two comments because I believe it's always nice to learn new things (which is why most of us are on this website). I find however quite interesting that in Québec, where every English expression *has* to be translated in French (cf. a famous movie called "Fiction Pulpeuse), saying "bienvenue" after "merci" is considered acceptable, since it makes absolutely no sense in French (it does mean "come on in", exactly as "welcome" originally is "well come").

Comment: "no worries" is Irish, in my experience, not Australian. However, the expression "arvo" meaning afternoon is one I wish was adopted in North America.

Comment: The Italians have a similar expression, "nessun problema" which many will translate into English as *no problem*. The idiom, *no problem* seems to be a loan one, I've heard Brits tell me: *no problemo* many a time when they find out I'm Italian. :)

Comment: @ArlaudPierre not to be nitpicking but it's **quibble** not *nibble* as to your first comment. And I doubt when speaking one hears if there is a space or not after an exclamation mark... mamma mia!

Comment: @anongoodnurse, Spaniard here, natively speaking Spanish (not studied). No idea of what is your context, but if those Spanish-speaking patients you mention are Mexican or from other latin-american countries, that would explain some strange-sounding (to Spaniards) Spanish. "No problema" is "Spanglish". Just like "carpeta" seems to be Mexican (?)/Spanglish for what in Spanish we call "alfombra" (carpet in English). Anyway, even if "ningún problema" is more grammatical, still sounds bad as an answer to "gracias" or similar. "Sin problema" sounds slightly better, but still suspicious.

Comment: @hmijail - Thanks for your comment!  This answer is very old. The Spanish-speaking patients are mostly from Puerto Rico, then Mexico, then a smattering of other Central American countries. I've often thought of this contentious answer/comment thread; I've even asked well-educated (one an MD, PhD) native Spanish speaking people (PR/M/Central American, but never Spaniards) about it, and received the same answer as I gave. Nice to hear from a Spaniard. Live and learn. Quebecois, my first tongue, is very different from Parisian French, that's for sure!

Answer (score 15):

Based on the other answers it seems not everyone has the following connotations with both terms, but I would argue that "No problem" implies that you did something out of the ordinary for someone, however that you did not consider it a problem. So in a sense you're disregarding the "thank you". In contrast "You're welcome" seems to imply that you appreciate their appreciation, as you in no way disregard their "Thank you".

Just to make it a bit clearer I have listed a number of responses to "Thank you" and how I would paraphrase the nuances hidden behind the reactions:

- "You're welcome" - *"You're welcome to what I just did for you"*
- "No problem" - *"You didn't even need to thank me, it wasn't a problem in the first place"*
- "My pleasure" - *"Making you happy already made it worth it, don't worry about thanking me"* or alternatively in a shop setting/trade setting it could also suggest *"It was my pleasure to make this deal with you"*
- "Anytime" - *"It was some trouble to me, but I would do it for you any time"*

So overall, in a shop setting I would expect them to appreciate the "thank you", so "you're welcome" seems to be the nicest response, although none of them seem to be incorrect or really wrong.

Comment: "Don't mention it" - *"It was trivial; I wouldn't care if you hadn't thanked me, in fact I would even prefer it!"*

Answer (score 10):

So much lies in context:

**"No problem"**

**Not as appropriate.**

"Thank you for having us over for this party, cooking this wonderful meal, and really the live band, renting the services of James Earl Jones just to say wacky things in his Darth Vader voice and the fireworks you set up by hand and injured yourself on really were appreciated."

"No problem."

Okay. The problem here is somebody's recognized a lot of effort you've undergone on their behalf as a guest at a lavish party. In a sense, you're turning around and saying "Well it was nothing to me really" which implies the guest wasn't worth much effort in your eyes. "You're welcome" works better here because it means you were glad to have made that effort for them. But it works best of course followed with "And thank you for coming etc..."

**More Appropriate**

<You held the door for somebody. They've thanked you.>

"No problem."

In this case, I'd say it's better than "You're welcome." Holding the door is a decent human thing too as is thanking someone for remembering to do it, but it really is no problem. To say "You're welcome" to a door-holding could be seen as slightly more pompous, making too big of a deal out of a very small thing that we forget to do for each other sometimes when somebody is carrying a bunch of stuff or has a bunch of kids in tow.

You can't really go wrong with either, but I do think people appreciate it when one is just a little bit more right, and that essentially boils down to the level of effort you actually undertook. If you've very obviously gone through a lot of effort, it's nicer to say that they are welcome to reap the benefits of that effort. If you're just being as polite as we all should be all the time I think "no problem" is a better fit for suggesting it's what we all should do for each other all the time and that you'd do it again without thinking about it.

Comment: Expressions like “no problem,” “no worries,” “it's nothing,” and their equivalents in other languages are an expression of humility. They don't mean that a service was no **effort,** but rather that it was no **bother** compared to what the recipient deserves. I'm not downvoting because clearly many people do take it the wrong way, but I think they're wrong to do so.

Comment: I like it when language makes sense. Often times, it does not. This answer is the way I think it _should_ be, but in practice I don't think this is how people use it. I have always wondered what a Spanish speaker might say to "Thank you for giving me your kidney. It saved my life..." I guess the answer is "It's nothing"

Comment: @BraddSzonye I don't necessarily disagree as there's an awful lot of room for gray area interpretation. But I think it's easier to take it one way rather than the other when the effort undertaken was clearly a great deal vs. just a polite thoughtful thing that didn't expend a ton of effort. Speaking as a sometimes awkward nerd raised by Norwegian immigrants, I have definitely offended when the intent was humility at times. Sometimes it's better to acknowledge the effort and that they were the reason you were happy to undertake it. But as I said, few would take either the wrong way.

Answer (score 6):

As a guide, one may wish to consider the form in which the thanks was expressed.

As a response to **'Thank you'** or **'Thank you very much,'** I'd personally recommend sticking with **'you're welcome'** or **'you're quite welcome!'** to not sound overly familiar.  One could also respond with **'It was no problem at all'** if it fits the service provided (e.g. you walked a half-block out of your way to show them where a store was located.)

If, the thanks was expressed as **'Thanks,'** the more informal **'no problem'** seems more in keeping with the tenor of the exchange.

My internal guide makes me want to err on the side of formality, but that is just me.

**Thank you so very much** for the opportunity to discuss this lively and interesting topic!

;-)

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 5):

I would say the level of politeness and etiquette of which words to use depends a lot on the country/region you are in.

For example, "no problem" may sound a little informal to you when thanking someone for delivering you a cup of coffee. However, in Australia and New Zealand, "no problem" would be commonplace, and may also be shortened to "no worries", "cheers", or even just a smile or nod in return. A full "you're welcome" can almost sound a bit forced and inauthentic.

Answer (score 5):

To me, the difference is in **what** is thanked for. I use *no problem* in a case, let's resume to the example of holding a door open, where the extra effort is almost the same. When two people want to go through a door, one of them has to open it anyway and - unless you are physically handicapped - holding it open for two seconds longer is no effort. Another example: making two cups of coffee instead of one is only a slight difference.

"You're welcome" instead I hear more often where there **is** an extra effort, but the person that is being done the favour is worth the extra effort to the person who does it. For example, watering your neighbours' plants when they are on vacation.

Answer (score 3):

When the coffee shop has less than one Michelin star, and is happy with that.

If they do want a Michelin star then it might still be perfectly okay to be that informal if they're going for a friendly vibe, because it's not like it's impolite or informal to the point of being overly familiar or anything.

Comment: My partner just told me that she was once criticised by a customer in a bar for saying "no problem". Personally, I'd have just ignored that customer for the rest of the night (or in one bar I once worked in, kicked them out, as it was a student bar with a strict no-rude-customers policy because drunk students can be hard to deal with otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

"No problem" is appropriate when someone is thanking you for doing them a favor -- something you went a little out of your way for out of kindness or consideration.

"You're welcome" is suitable for cases unlike the above, such as being thanked for a party invitation (which was planned and meaningful) or a paid service (where it was the server's responsibility to do what they did).

That's what creates the sense of it being casual vs. formal, as noted in the other answers, and this taxonomy fits the other examples.

Answer (score 2):

To add another opinion that hasn't been considered yet... I would say it depends on the intent of the thanker. Sometimes "Thank you" can be more "I'm sorry to have bothered you/put you out of your way" than actually expressing gratitude. In Japanese "sumimasen" (sorry/excuse me) is sometimes used where in English we would say "Thank you".

I would say if the thanker is feeling/looking a bit apologetic, then "Don't worry about it" or "No problem" is a more appropriate response. For example, perhaps they asked you for directions and you started giving them, but the directions turned out to be more complicated than either of you realised, so you ended up walking in the opposite direction with them for a little while. Or you are a salesperson in a shop and a customer asked you for another size of clothes - you looked on the shop floor, then the backroom, then looked it up in the catalogue, then rang other stores, etc. In these cases their "thank you" might be more apologetic, because they were asking you for more than they originally realised they were asking you for. So you let them know with a reply like "No trouble at all!" or "No problem!" to let them know that it doesn't matter.

However, if it's something that you planned to do for the thanker - like you bought them a really nice present, or you invited them to your house and cooked dinner, then they're not feeling anxious or apologetic, they're just grateful. So in this instance you say "You're welcome" to acknowledge that they are thanking you and let them know that you were happy to do whatever it was. "I was happy to" would also be an appropriate reply in this case if they've expressed the thanks as "Thank you for doing X".

Answer (score 1):

I have many relatives (native English speakers) who are offended by "no problem." (I myself use "no problem," or sometimes "yep!" in informal response to "thank you.") Still, I would recommend "you're welcome" in all contexts except with friends, in case your listener is like one of my relatives. (I think a lot of "no problem" users don't realize that they come across as rude to some folks.)

Answer (score -1):

I'm an American expat living in German, and I've noticed this trend over the last few years from my compatriots. I also don't find "No problem" appropriate in many cases, but it does seem to be the norm now - at least in the United States.  It's annoying because my German students are using it, too, in situations where "You're welcome" would be the appropriate reply.  I attribute the over use of "No problem" to the dumbing down of the education system. Many people have a very limited vocabulary and may not even be aware that "No problem" doesn't fit the situation.

"You're welcome" is still good enough for me. It is polite and friendly.

Comment: [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/no-problem) says it's "used as a friendly answer when someone thanks you for something you have done". It notes it as informal, but I don't see why you'd think it was *wrong*, or indicative of "dumbing down". It's simply short for "it was no problem(to do it)".

Comment: Please provide references to support claims that the usage is inappropriate. Referring to common practices as “dumbing down” without support is inflammatory.

Comment: I agree that Babs' claim of "dumbing down" is perhaps too harsh, but it does reflect the idea that people are choosing one reply for all situations instead of the appropriate reply for each situation. It's not like "Hi" (informal) versus "I'm pleased to meet you" (formal), it's a matter of saying, "I acknowledge your thanks, but what I did was natural/expected" (that is "No problem") versus "Thank you for acknowledging that I went out of my way for you. (That is "You're welcome")