# Can “no problem” ever replace “OK,” "yes, of course," etc., when the respondent has been called to task?

Tags: phrase-usage

Unlike the use of "no problem" as an alternative to "you're welcome" or "my pleasure," neither of which bothers me much in common speech, its use as a reply to an instruction or directive to put right what the respondent has done wrong, particularly if at great expense or at substantial loss of available time, tests my patience and my temper. To my Boomer-generation ear, it says the respondent somehow feels that s/he is doing me a favor by setting things right rather than accepting responsibility for them, and somehow cannot see that a problem truly is involved. Is this a generational shift that I should get used to, or is the use of "no problem" in this context an erroneous use of this expression?  (For now, at least.)

Comment: Please refer also to the following ELU question on the usage of 'no problem':http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/when-should-no-problem-replace-youre-welcome-as-a-response-to-thank-you

Comment: Arguably a stylistic error for the reasons you mention, but not more than that.

Comment: I understand the logical point you are making, but I think you may be attributing too much fecklessness to your respondents. Most likely, their usage conforms to the habitual formula of their peer group, with no implications of irresponsibility intended.

Comment: *No problem* is short for *it is/was no problem for me to do this/that.*  It does not mean that there is/was no problem in general.

Comment: Could you give examples of this use? I'm having trouble coming up with the context you're referring to.

Comment: @Barmar: I find that I cannot give a very concrete example without fingerpointing. This is the best I can do in this context: Recurring Task A must be completed soon because complicated Project  B is about to begin. The assignment is to keep Task A simple and to complete it quickly. It is finished a day late, has been done much more elaborately than necessary, and does not fully address the problem it was intended to resolve. Others will need to do this person's work on the project while the task is being set right. When told to set it right, the person says nothing but, "No problem."

Comment: @Anonym - Whatever "No Problem" is short for, using it when the speaker has caused the problem under discussion still seems rude and thoughtless to me.

Comment: @JoanPederson  That's unfortunate.  You know what the speaker means; you're intentionally misunderstanding the speaker when you interpret in that way.

Comment: @JoanPederson It doesn't sound like "No problem" is a reaction to being called to task, but to his project being taken away from him. He's avoiding answering to the criticism or apologizing for the shoddy work.

Comment: So he's saying "I have no problem with someone else taking over this task."

Comment: Another reaction you might encounter is something like "Good luck with that", if he thinks he did as well as could be expected, is being unfairly criticized, and the new implementor is unlikely to be able to improve on his work.

Comment: The person's project isn't being taken away. It's being handed back and needs to be done over. The person is grudgingly accepting the need to redo it, is feeling put upon, and is showing no recognition that the aspect of the work that was poorly done has had a negative ripple effect on several others, and that some acknowledgement of responsibility, if not apology, would be offered by a genuine adult.

Answer (score 2):

'No problem' is often just a confirmation that an instruction has been received and that there is no problem with executing said instruction. I'm of the generation that uses it in this context, but if I was being disciplined or reprimanded I wouldn't use it - I'd consider it to be too familiar in that context. Worth noting that using language that is too familiar is not the same as being intentionally unhelpful or obstructive, though.

Comment: Thanks for that context, Thomas. I'll understand it that way whenever possible, and will hope that that's the context in which it's offered.