# Alternatives to "You're Welcome"

Tags: synonyms, idiom-requests

I've noticed there are a lot of alternatives in English to "Thank you", but I am struggling to come up with any for "You're welcome", though it would be said nearly as often.

Can someone please point me to some good alternatives, or a resource that could provide them?

Comment: Have you seen the [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) site?

Comment: @marcellothearcane I don't see how that is relevant.

Comment: Merely for a point of interest. This question would also be at home on that site, I venture.

Comment: "De nada", although not English, is used by a lot of English speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responses to "Thank you" could include

- You're welcome
- No problem (or Not a problem)
- No trouble
- No worries
- My pleasure
- Happy to (help)
- Not at all
- Don't mention it
- Anytime
- No, thank *you*
- (no direct response at all)

See [earlier](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/how-do-native-english-speakers-respond-to-thank-you) [questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/when-should-no-problem-replace-youre-welcome-as-a-response-to-thank-you) for some discussion